# MySQL: data missing after adding Primary Key

Tags: mysql, insert, primary-key

I've just found some very strange behaviour after adding a Primary Key to a table. Before creating the key, there were 6,672 rows in the table. After creating the key, there were 103. However if the key is created on the empty table and THEN the same data added there are 6,672 rows. And yes, all the values used to make the Primary key are/were unique.
The code I ran is below.

The table is 'WC':

```
CREATE TABLE `wc` (
  `gvkey` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `date_fin` date NOT NULL,
  `wc` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `wc_less_debt_st` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `curr_liab_x` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `wc_adj` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `wc_adj_v2` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gvkey`,`date_fin`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

After creating the table the following code was run:

```
ALTER TABLE wc
DROP PRIMARY KEY;

DELETE FROM wc;

INSERT INTO wc (date_fin, gvkey)
SELECT DISTINCT u.udate, g.gvkey 
FROM gvkey as g INNER JOIN udate as u
WHERE g.flag = TRUE;

ALTER TABLE wc
ADD PRIMARY KEY `gvkey-date` (gvkey asc, date_fin asc);
```

To test the size of the table:

```
SELECT COUNT(gvkey) FROM (SELECT gvkey FROM wc GROUP BY gvkey) AS x;
```

If the test is run before adding the Primary key, the result is 6,672. When run after creating the key the result is 103. If I then move the call

```
ALTER TABLE wc
    ADD PRIMARY KEY `gvkey-date` (gvkey asc, date_fin asc);
```

to immediately after `delete from wc` and then run the `INSERT` then it works fine resulting in 6,672 rows in the table.

I've previously run into a few issues adding primary keys to tables that are already populated with data but it was never this obvious.

Is this known behaviour and is it bad practise to add primary keys to populated tables? My motivation for doing it in this order (populate then create PK) was because I thought the insert would run faster without a primary key. Although it doesn't matter for this table, I'm working with a few tables that have more than 3m records. I'm fairly new to database management so any suggestions or explanations would be greatly appreciated. I haven't found any mention of this anywhere else.

Thanks,

Comment: How many rows does the `SELECT DISTINCT` query return? 6k or 100?

Comment: @SalmanA, The SELECT DISTINCT returns 6,672 rows.